# 24 Hour time range in pandas DataFrame Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

The Input file I have received is:

[image]

I have to transform above dataframe, and I want to have a column which has 'time interval' like 00:00 - 01:00 for every day(24 hour), I want to know if there is any pandas function to accomplish this task. The time interval should repeat for next day as well.

Output DataFrame :
[image]

The column 'ID' have many categorical field in it. And I have to do this for all the categorical field in the column. The 'Date' columns is a date_range derived using :

```
pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range(start=start, end=End, freq='1D')})
```

Here, start = min(start_date), End = max(end_date)

The 'Hour' column is derived:

```
pd.date_range(start, End, freq="60min").strftime('%H:%M')
```

I tried using `pd.interval_range` but that didnt help the cause.

Comment: Your *I/O* don't match! Can you double-check ? Also, what's the purpose of the `"End Time"` ? The start and end times have always the same date ? For example, could the id `abc` have an interval of `11/1/2021` and `12/1/2021 6:00` ?

Comment: @Timeless, The Input file is what I have received and for each ID the start time and end time is there, these are in datetime format. Importing to excel might have removed it, but its like start time `11/1/2021 06:04` and end time `11/1/2021 06:10`. And there could be multiple start time and end time with minutes difference for each ID.

Comment: You didn't answer the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#convert to datetimes
df['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'], dayfirst=True)
df['End Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Time'], dayfirst=True)

#create 24H periods
r = df['End Time'].dt.normalize().sub(df['Start Time']).dt.days.add(1).mul(24)

#repeat rows by 24H
df = (df.loc[df.index.repeat(r), ['ID','Start Time']]
        .rename(columns={'Start Time':'Date'})
        .reset_index(drop=True))

#create helepr datetimes for hours
h = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', freq='h', periods=len(df))

#if End - Start difference is multiple days add them
d = df['Date'].add(pd.to_timedelta(df.index // 24, unit='D')).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

#format of Time Intervals
ti = h.strftime('%H:%M') + ' - '  + (h + pd.Timedelta(1, 'H')).strftime('%H:%M')

#assign new columns
out = df.assign(**{'Date': d, 'Hour': h.strftime('%H:%M'), 'Time Interval':ti})
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though I don't see the purpose of the column `"End Time"`, you can [`interval_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.interval_range.html#pandas.interval_range)  :

```
h24_ranges = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [
            "{:%#H:%M}".format(ir.left.time()),
            "{:%H:%M}-{:%H:%M}".format(ir.left.time(), ir.right.time())
        ]
    for s in df["Start Time"]
        for ir in pd.interval_range(s, s+pd.Timedelta(24, unit="H"), freq="1H")
    ], index= df.index.repeat(24), columns= ["Hour", "Time Interval"]
)

out = df.drop("End Time", axis=1).join(h24_ranges)#.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

     ID Start Time   Hour Time Interval
0   abc 2021-11-01   0:00   00:00-01:00
0   abc 2021-11-01   1:00   01:00-02:00
0   abc 2021-11-01   2:00   02:00-03:00
0   abc 2021-11-01   3:00   03:00-04:00
0   abc 2021-11-01   4:00   04:00-05:00
..  ...        ...    ...           ...
3   asd 2021-11-01  19:00   19:00-20:00
3   asd 2021-11-01  20:00   20:00-21:00
3   asd 2021-11-01  21:00   21:00-22:00
3   asd 2021-11-01  22:00   22:00-23:00
3   asd 2021-11-01  23:00   23:00-00:00

[96 rows x 4 columns]
```